# Multiple points on multiple polygons SQL Server Spatial

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

I am a bit newbie on SQL server spatial.

I've been running a job on SQL server using 2 spatial databases "points"(>1m entries) and "polygons"(>800 entries)

what I want to do is simply create a Boolean field that tells me if a point falls in a polygon.
I have tried a few things but nothing conclusive or productive.
The Query I have tried was:

```
SELECT
    points_id,
    CASE
        WHEN p1.GEOM.STWithin((p2.GEOM))=1 
        THEN 'yes' 
        ELSE 'no'
    END as results
FROM [pointsdb] p1, [polydb] p2
```

the results I get are basically all the possible combinations of 1 point to all polygons and vice versa.
I tried to use a group by but the effiency gone down a lot.

Could you help me on that?
cheers

Comment: By doing a cartesian product of the two tables you are generating a 800 x 1M records resultset. What is your actual expected result?

Comment: What do you mean "create a Boolean field"? Don't you just want a function to check that one point is in one polygon? Doesn't checking `p1.GEOM.STWithin((p2.GEOM))=1` already do that?

Comment: My expected result is to know if 1 point falls within a polygon, if it does assign the value with "yes" if not "no", and then go to the next point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not cross join the tables. Instead, you can use an `exists` condition with correlated subquery, as follows:

```
SELECT
    points_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [polydb] p2 
            WHERE p1.GEOM.STWithin((p2.GEOM))=1 
        ) 
        THEN 'yes' 
        ELSE 'no'
    END as results
FROM [pointsdb] p1
```

Comment: That does the job Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @Dnl_! Glad that it helped.